# Django Faker, populating a users model

Tags: django

Using this link as a reference(https://medium.com/@sharma.ashish.1996/populating-database-with-faker-library-794ec0976a99) and an online django course, I made a population script to create fake users for the website on django 1.11. It generally works just that the first and last names are exactly the same (e.g. Sprinkle Sprinkle) and it only populates one user at a time, is there something wrong with the populating script?

Thanks!

Best regards

```
import os

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE','ProTwo.settings')

import django
django.setup()

from AppTwo.models import User
from faker import Faker

fakegen= Faker()


def populate(N=5):

    for entry in range(N):
        fake_name= fakegen.name().split()
        fake_first_name = fake_name[0]
        fake_last_name = fake_name[1]
        fake_email= fakegen.email()


    #new entry

    user = User.objects.get_or_create(first_name = fake_last_name,last_name= fake_last_name,email = fake_email)[0]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('populating databases')
    populate(20)
    print('populated')
```

Answer (score 1):

this code  will create only one user because of the missing indentation of the 'user = User.objects...'
It should be:

def populate(N=5):

```
for entry in range(N):
    fake_name= fakegen.name().split()
    fake_first_name = fake_name[0]
    fake_last_name = fake_name[1]
    fake_email= fakegen.email()
    #new entry
    user = User.objects.get_or_create...
```